# How to start 2 programs that need separate terminals from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 programs that I want to run, programA.py and programB.py.  When I run them manually, I have to open separate terminals and type the following commands:

```
terminal1
python programA.py

terminal2
python programB.py
```

Each of these programs then output some data on the command line.  Lastly, programA.py has to be fully started and waiting before programB.py can start (takes ~2s for programA.py to start and be ready to accept data).

If I am running these programs in Ubuntu, how can I write a bash script that accomplishes that?  Right now, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python programA.py
python programB.py
```

This starts programA.py, but because programA.py then waits for input, programB.py doesn't start until you close out of programA.py.  How can I change my script to run the two programs simultaneously?

Edit:

Using the advice given by Andreas Neumann below, changing the script to the following successfully launches the two programs:

```
#!/bin/bash
python programA.py &
sleep 5
python programB.py &
```

However, when both programs are launched, the code then doesn't work properly.  Basically, programA.py is setting up a listening socket, and then creates an interface that the user works with.  programB.py then starts afterwards, and runs a process, talking to programA.py over the sockets.  When running the above script, programA starts, waits, programB starts, and then programA and B connect, form the interface, but then programB isn't running its background processes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you find my original answer below doesn't work, yet you still want to solve your question with a single script, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "python ProgramA.py" &
sleep 5
python ProgramB.py
```

**Original Answer**

If `programA` is creating a user interface, you probably need that to be in the foreground, so start `programB` in the background:

```
{ sleep 5; python programB.py; } &
python ProgramA.py
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error `syntax error near unexpected token '}'`

Comment: Are you using `bash`? Did you include the semi-colons?

Comment: You can replace `{...}` with `(...)`

Comment: Yes, using bash, and semi-colons were included.

Comment: Ok, replacing `{...}` with `(...)` allows it to run.  However, again the program isn't functioning properly.  The UI created with programA appears, but programB isn't communicating with the devices that it is supposed to talk to.

Comment: Ok, sorry it didn't work out for you. I suspect we're going to need to see your code to work it out.

Comment: At this point, I have permission to just use two separate scripts, so I'm going to just leave it at that and call it good enough.

Comment: I presume you realise you can start the second script in the second terminal  from the first terminal by doing `xterm -e "python ProgramA.py" &`.

Comment: No, I hadn't realized that I could start the second script in a second terminal.  However, your updated solution works perfectly, and I will be updating my script now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
python programA.py &
sleep 5 # give enough time to start
python programB.py &
```

Comment: This starts `programB.py` *immediately*, without the pause needed to allow `programA.py` to start up first.

Comment: using `screen`could also be a nicer approach because you can have a look at both programs outputs

Comment: This script successfully starts both programs.  However, for some reason then the two programs then don't work properly.  Note that if I were to have a script that does `python programA.py` and a second that does `python programB.py` and run them manually (in separate windows), the programs then function properly.

Comment: @Andreas Neumann - I edited my original question above to include some details about how the code is failing